# Is there a way to capture the value of a variable in each iteration of a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, loops, for-loop

I am a student learning javascript, it is only week 3 so I am not familiar with any advanced topics or code.  This is for a graded assignment so I am not looking for answers but any help or suggestions to accomplish this would be great.  I have been stuck for several hours and I really don't even know what direction to head in.

What I need to do is use a for loop to grab the value of upto 3 different id tags that a user can enter into an html page.  it has to be done in a for loop and use a counter to change the name of the id sequentially.

I am able to do this, however every time the loop runs it grabs the data and of course sets the variable to the latest iteration of the loop.

Is there a way to capture the returned value in each loop and store it for use later after the loop has run?  I should be able to generate 3 separate values and then display them together.

Edit: this is the HTML:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<body>
  <h1>Assignment 2</h1>
  <p>
    Enter First Name:
    <input id="firstname" type="text">
    <span id="firstname_error">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Enter Last Name:
    <input id="lastname" type="text">
    <span id="lastname_error">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    How Many Pets do you have? (0-3):
    <input id="numpets" maxlength="1" size="1" type="text">
    <span id="numpets_error">*</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    List your Pet's names:
    <input id="pet1" type="text">
    <input id="pet2" type="text">
    <input id="pet3" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
     <input onclick="processInfo()" type="button" value="Submit Information">
  </p>
  <p id="message">*</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depends on the HTML.  Please post a snippet.

Comment: You can store the value from each iteration in another variable like a string or an array.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I haven't learned about arrays yet, but when I store it as a string, it gets overwritten every time the loop runs.  So I successfully grab the value, but can't store it without it getting written over on the next loop.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: My professor provided this .<h1>Assignment 2</h1><p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname">  <span id="firstname_error">*</span></p>
<p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname">  <span id="lastname_error">*</span></p>
<p>How Many Pets do you have?  (0-3): <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1">
<span id="numpets_error">*</span></p>
<p>List your Pet's names:
<input type="text" id="pet1">
<input type="text" id="pet2">
<input type="text" id="pet3">
</p><p><input type="button" value="Submit Information" onClick="processInfo()"><p id="message">*</p>

Comment: If you'd use a string, first create an empty string: `var result='';` Then append the results like `result+= 'piece of string to add' ;` (this means: `result=result+'piece of string to add';`). If you'd use a unique separation character you could also split it on that same character (to an array). However, using the array is probably better (and an extremely useful concept to grasp)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a separate variable to cumulatively store the value from each iteration. Make sure to define this variable *before* the loop and to *add* the data to the variable at each iteration, instead of overwriting it.

For example with a `string` variable:

```
var str = '';
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    str += i+' '; // Note the usage of the += operator to append the value
}
 //
console.log(str);
```

Or with an `array` variable:

```
var arr = [];
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
 //
console.log(arr.toString());
```

Note that for the sake of the example we're just storing the values of the loop's counter, `i`.

Comment: Thanks!  I will give this a try it looks like it is what I was trying to do!

Comment: @user2780236 No problem. Updated the answer with more relevant information, following your comments above.